# Why does my Python script not read all the lines from the file, or why does it not write all of the lines to the new file?

Tags: python, file-io

I have written a little script to remove lines from a file. The problem is that it only writes the first 42 entries I want.

Code:

```
import fileinput
filename = "trip.txt"
phrase = '$GPGLL'
newfile = open("modifed_trip.txt", "w")

with fileinput.input(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if phrase in line:
            newfile.write(line)
newfile.close()
```

File size = 4,209 KB

Number of lines = 100825

Why does this script not read all the lines from the file, or why does it not write all of the lines to the new file?

P.S. This does seem to select the lines I would like to copy into the new file, for the first 42 lines matching the phrase.

Edit:
As per @NimaZera's comment I made changes to this affect:

```
with open("trip2-Copy2.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        if phrase in line:
            newfile.write(line)
newfile.close()
```

This left me with this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4283: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Would the same thing happen if you used `with open("trip.txt") as f:    content = f.readlines()` ?

Comment: How do you know it isn't reading all the lines?  Try ```for line_no, line in enumerate(f):``` - what is ```line_no``` after the iteration?

Comment: I don't know that it isn't reading all the lines, hence the ambiguity of my question. I will try this when I get home from work. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker The encoding was the problem. We converted both the file and the script to utf-8. Thanks! Also if you want to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file seems to be using a non-ASCII encoding. Unless your Python script happens to be encoded using the same encoding as your file, you'll need to declare the encoding when opening the file.

In Python 3, the default encoding is UTF-8; in Python 2, you need to declare that encoding at the top of your script:

```
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-
```

or explicitly use that encoding when opening the file:

```
with codecs.open("trip-Copy2.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    # do something
```